# Unknown marine mammal call - low frequency - Evans Strait, Hudson Bay

Tags: marine-species, species-identification, marine-mammals, sound-library, call-identification

I am working on a marine mammal survey off the coasts of Southampton Island, Hudson Bay. After checking several sound libraries, I have not been able to identify the species that makes the call below.

The sound was recorded throughout the month of November, during the start of sea ice freeze-up. The mooring was deployed in Evans Strait, it was 200 m deep and 30 km from the closest shore.

[image: Example of a spectrogram of a call from an unknown species]

Comment: Hi Veronica. Stack Exchange is a website for Q&A. I hope you don't mind me saying this, but it seems this post is not really asking a question that might have a definite answer, it seems more like you are more generally starting a discussion. Stack Exchange isn't intended for that. .... Or if I interpret things differently: your question is a "meta question" about the site itself, so it shouldn't be here but should be on https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Welcome @veronica! As @Dan stated…this question is really two questions (or could become 2!) The first part asking about this type of question has been asked here: https://bioacoustics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/what-about-unknown-sounds

Could you edit your question to just be about the spectrogram you shared? If you provide more detail on where it was recorded (depth, location, dist to shore, season) maybe someone can help ID!

Comment: @veronica thanks for editing! I hope someone can chime in with a suggestion.

Comment: Any chance you can upload a sound clip via SoundCloud? I think hearing it will also help (me at least!)

Comment: Veronica, in anticipation of future similar questions, can you edit the title of the question to reflect something unique to your recording? Maybe "Unknown marine mammal call - Evans Strait" or something like that

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestions. I will edit this and add an audio file :)

Answer (score 2):

I second the last comment - many of us listen to audio to identify sounds. If you can include a link to a sound clip someone may be able to tell you if those impulsive sounds are clicks, knocks, grunts, croaks, snaps, etc.

I do not study low frequency sounds, but I would try to look at what sounds are produced by fishes in that region. Below are some examples of fish sounds from the DOSITS sound library:

https://dosits.org/galleries/audio-gallery/fishes/haddock/

https://dosits.org/galleries/audio-gallery/fishes/atlantic-croaker/

https://dosits.org/galleries/audio-gallery/fishes/barred-grunt/